# Pipe limit characters with breaks on angular 2

Tags: angular

Drop down input have a long description in every options, how can i do with br after every 100 characters.

```
[value]="val.id">{{val.name}}-{{val.description}}
```

Comment: Isn't that something you would typically do with CSS instead of adding <br> in HTML?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: here is the code in my service : 

 {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "E",
  "description": "Tarif für Einkünfte, die im vereinfachten Abrechnungsverfahren besteuert werden"
 },

and this description i want to split in 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice like this `{{ val.description | slice: 0:41 }}
<br />
{{ val.description | slice: 41:79 }}` . You can create a loop if you want the line break to repeat, or you can make a custom pipe just for this.